# How to moniter network usage through my Dongle, not laptop

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager

I have been using nethogs to track my network usage but it seems to only track usage to and from my laptop. I would like to track all usage that passes through my mobile wifi unit. I have allowed people to "borrow" borrow my connection, but have a data limit so would like to keep an eye on how much they are using. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You've just gotta tell nethogs what interface you're trying to keep an eye on

```
nethogs eth0
```

A few more helpful bits

```
-m : Change the units displayed for the bandwidth in units like KB/sec -> KB -> B-> MB.
-r : Sort by magnitude of respectively traffic.
-s : Sort by magnitude of sent traffic.
-q : Hit quit to the shell prompt.
```

Comment: I get this `sudo nethogs eth0`

`ioctl failed while establishing local IP for selected device eth0. You may specify the device on the command line.`